# Eclipse gives error for 'undefined' Java function it can easily find

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I've been having trouble with Eclipse. I'm working on a java project that's configured with git. After submitting my code through git, Eclipse suddenly generates all these errors, saying many functions are undefined. However all the functions are still there, Eclipse will even take me to them when Ctrl+click the function.

For instance say I have this class:

```
public class myClass {

    public myClass () {}

    public void myFunction () {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

And now I have another class that uses it:

```
public class secondClass {
    public void callFunction () {
        myClass a = new myClass();
        a.myFunction();
    }
}
```

The myFunction call in secondClass causes an 'undefined' error in Eclipse. I've tried refreshing the project but it doesn't make a difference. The only way I've found to get Eclipse to behave correctly is to comment out the function it can't find, uncomment it, and then save the file. Is there a better way to do this? Or prevent Eclipse from having this problem?

Comment: did you import `myClass` in `secondClass`?

Comment: Try to refresh or clean the project. If the trouble remains, open 'Problem view' and manually delete the problem. Then clean again.

Comment: please start class names with Uppercase.

Comment: How exactly is your project configured with git?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Yes, `myClass` is imported in `secondClass`. Both classes were working fine, until I ran 'git review'

@nitind My project is actually configured with gerrit. Sorry I should've put that in the headline instead of git. After I run `git review` and the change is approved, suddenly the project has errors where there weren't any before.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something is going wrong with your eclipse.

When this happens I typically do the following. (Continue to the next bullet if previous did not help):

1. refresh the project. First try F5. If it does not help do it using right click on project and choosing the appropriate option in context menu. It is strange, but sometimes F5 does not work, but menu does.
2. rebuild the project.
3. Try to close project and open it again
4. try to delete project (without removing content) through Eclipse.
5. try to create project again and copy *.java files there.
6. try to create new workspace.

I hope that #1 (or probably #2) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have properly imported myClass in secondClass.

Secondly, your class naming is wrong. Class names generally starts with a capital letter.

Comment: it's not wrong actually, it's just a convention, as you say, which of course should be followed.

Answer (score 0):

From your 'solution' it seems to me the imports have gone missing. Commenting and then uncommenting the method and saving the file caused eclipse to fix your imports.

You have to take a look at the way you commit/push your code through git (and who did the last change), there is probably something wrong in the workflow that causes them to commit a file with missing import statements.